# Потокобезопасная проверка состояния

Tags: java, многопоточность, инспекция-кода

- **Задача:** Есть клиенты, которые подключаются к серверу и периодически выполняют какие-то операции. Если за некоторое время клиент не провел ни одной операции, то в базе его статус меняется на оффлайн. При возобновлении операция статус в БД меняется на онлайн. Клиенты живут в разных потоках.
- **Нагрузка:**

  - Клиентов порядка 100-200
  - средняя частота операций порядка секунды-двух
  - время бездействия: 5 минут
- **Алгоритм:**

  - Есть `Map` у которого ключ - это ID клиента, а значение - время истечения ожидания. Клиенты сдвигают это время при каждом обращении к серверу.
  - Есть таймер, который срабатывает раз в минуту, пробегает по списку клиентов, находит тех, у которых истекло время ожидания, удаляет их из списка и меняет статус в базе.
- **Реализация:**

  ```
  public class ActiveClientManager implements Consumer<Integer> {
    private final Map<Integer, Long> clients;
    private final PoolDataSource pds;
    private final long timeout;
    private final Object dbMonitor;

    public ActiveClientManager(PoolDataSource pds, long timeout) {
      clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
      this.pds = pds;
      this.timeout = timeout;
      dbMonitor = new Object();
    }

    // Действие клиента
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer clientID) {
      // Время после которого, клиент уходит в оффлайн
      long offlineTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
      // Вставляем нового клиента, или обновляем существующего
      if (clients.put(clientID, offlineTime) == null) {
          // Если была произведена вставка, то меняем статус в базе
          try {
              try (Connection con = pds.getConnection()) {
                  try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clients SET state = 1 WHERE id = ?")) {
                      stmt.setInt(1, clientID);
                      // Перекрываем кислород таймеру
                      synchronized (dbMonitor) {
                          stmt.executeUpdate();
                      }
                  }
              }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
    }

    // Обработка события таймера
    public void testTimeout() throws SQLException {
      long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      // Сюда занесем всех клиентов, которые уже отвалились
      List<Integer> removeClients = new ArrayList<>();
      clients.replaceAll((key, val) -> {
          if (val <= currentTime) {
              // если время уже прошло, то сохраняем нашего клиента
              removeClients.add(key);
              // и удаляем его из общего списка
              return null;
          }
          // иначе ничего не трогаем
          return val;
      });
      // если есть кого удалять
      if (removeClients.size() > 0) {
          try (Connection con = pds.getConnection()) {
              try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clients SET state = NULL WHERE id = ?")) {
                  // блокируем добавление нового клиента
                  synchronized (dbMonitor) {
                      for (Integer client : removeClients) {
                          // если клиент не появился опять в общем списке
                          if (!clients.containsKey(client)) {
                              // то сбрасываем ему статус
                              stmt.setInt(1, client);
                              stmt.executeUpdate();
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Собственно вопрос - не упустил ли я, что-либо в синхронизации?

**Update**

Выяснилось, что конструкция

```
clients.replaceAll((key, val) -> {
    if (val <= currentTime) {
        // если время уже прошло, то сохраняем нашего клиента
        removeClients.add(key);
        // и удаляем его из общего списка
        return null;
    }
    // иначе ничего не трогаем
    return val;
});
```

не работает. Если из лямбды вернуть `null`, то метод бросает NullPointerException. Переписал так

```
clients.entrySet().removeIf((entry) -> {
    if (entry.getValue() <= currentTime) {
        removeClients.add(entry.getKey());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Меня смущает использование synchronized  в методе accept после того, как произошло обращение к clients, а в методе testTimeout обращение к clients и без synchronized  и в секции synchronized. Если у Вас обращение происходит из нескольких потоков к данной карте. может быть стоит использовать потокобезопасную структуру из пакета concurrent или же обращаться только в synchronized  блоке?

Comment: @ezhov_da Обращение к map потокобезопасно `clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`. А `synchronized` у меня используется для синхронизации базы. Чтобы статусы в базе не разбежались с реальной картиной

Comment: Да, не увидел ConcurrentHashMap,тогда лично я не вижу проблем )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синхронизируясь по одному объекту `dbMonitor` вы ограничиваете паралелльность вашего решения. То есть, клиенты будут "ждать" базу данных, даже если они с разным `clientId`. Если использовать встроенную синхронизацию в `ConcurrentHashMap`, то получится большая "паралленость" `ActiveClientManager`'а.

Но конечно же лучше проверить производительность тестами. Попробуйте создать менеджер, и вызвать методы `accept`, `testTimeout` из разных потоков.

Не претендую на абсолютную истинность решения, указал лишь на то, что бросилось в глаза.

Пример:

```
public class ActiveClientManager implements Consumer<Integer> {
    private final Map<Integer, Long> clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final PoolDataSource pds;
    private final long timeout;

    public ActiveClientManager(PoolDataSource pds, long timeout) {
        this.pds = pds;
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    // Действие клиента
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer clientID) {
        // Время после которого, клиент уходит в оффлайн
        long offlineTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
        // Вставляем нового клиента, или обновляем существующего
        // синхронизируемся только если один и тот же clientID
        clients.compute(clientID, (oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (oldVal == null) {
                try {
                    try (Connection con = pds.getConnection()) {
                        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clients SET state = 1 WHERE id = ?")) {
                            stmt.setInt(1, clientID);
                            stmt.executeUpdate();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return offlineTime;
        });
    }

    // Обработка события таймера
    public void testTimeout() throws SQLException {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Сюда занесем всех клиентов, которые уже отвалились
        // синхронизируемся на конерктном client
        clients.replaceAll((client, val) -> {
            if (val <= currentTime) {
                // если время уже прошло, то сохраняем нашего клиента
                try (Connection con = pds.getConnection()) {
                    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clients SET state = NULL WHERE id = ?")) {
                        // блокируем добавление нового клиента
                        stmt.setInt(1, client);
                        stmt.executeUpdate();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // и удаляем его из общего списка
                return null;
            }
            // иначе ничего не трогаем
            return val;
        });
    }
}
```

**Update**
По второй реализации бросается к глаза, что Вы не определились, что делать если база не работает(или возвращает ошибки). В первом случае - `accept` вы собираете список исключений, и пытаетесь обновлять "хоть каких-то" клиентов, даже если база начинает "сбоить". А в втором случае - `testTimeout` просто логируете сообщение в консоль.
На вашем месте, я бы в обоих случаях бросал RuntimeException, потому что продолжать работать при не работающей базе кажется не логично. Но это зависит от того как Вы работаете с исключениями выше по коду.

Насчет двух циклов, логично не создавать коннект к базе, если он не нужен. Но два идентичных условия проверки - лишь усложняют код. И в будущем если Вам понадобится изменить условие придется менять в двух местах. Я бы оставил создание коннекта внутри.

Так же кажется, что код по работе с базой логично вынести в два отдельных метода или даже объединить в один.

Есть ощущение, что интерфейс Consumer здесь лишний. Напрашивается интерфейс с двумя методами get(), put(). Так же из кода не ясно кто будет вызывать метод`testTimeout`. Кажется, что этот метод должен вызывать сам менеджер, через какой-то промежуток времени, ведь это его зона отвественности - поддержка в актуальном состоянии статусов клиентов. Тогда следует завести например `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`, и в нем поток который будет вызывать приватный метод `testTimeout`.

**Обновленная версия**

```
public class ActiveClientManager implements Consumer<Integer> {
    private final Map<Integer, Long> clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();;
    private final PoolDataSource pds;
    private final long timeoutMSec;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public ActiveClientManager(PoolDataSource pds, long timeoutMSec) throws SQLException {
        this.pds = pds;
        this.timeoutMSec = timeoutMSec;
        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::testTimeout, 5 ,5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    private void testTimeout() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        clients.entrySet().removeIf((entry) -> {
            // если время уже прошло
            if (entry.getValue() < currentTime) {
                // обновляем БД
                updateState(entry.getKey(), State.notactive);
                // удаляем этот элемент
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    private void updateState(Integer clientId, State state) {
        try (Connection con = pds.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clients SET state = " + state.getSqlState()  + " WHERE id = ?");) {
            stmt.setInt(1, clientId);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Integer clientID) {
        long offlineTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeoutMSec;
        clients.compute(clientID, (key, oldval) -> {
            // Если запись новая - обновляем БД
            if (oldval == null) {
                updateState(clientID, State.active);
            }
            return offlineTime;
        });
    }

    public enum State {
        active("1"), notactive("NULL");

        private final String sqlState;

        State(String sqlState) {
            this.sqlState = sqlState;
        }

        public String getSqlState() {
            return sqlState;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, похоже на правду. Единственное что, наверное для удаления имеет сделать два цикла. Первым найти а есть ли объекты для удаления, потом создать коннект и запустить поиск повторно

Comment: а посмотрите на вторую реализацию

Comment: @AntonShchyrov обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за замечания. testTimout вызывается снаружи из таймера именно из-за необходимости получить исключение (работа с исключениями в приведенном коде сильно упрощена). Проверку на истечение времени вынес в отдельный метод и вызываю его дважды. Обновление БД тоже повыносил в отдельный метод.

Answer (score 0):

С учетом замечания @volyx получился такой класс

```
public class ActiveClientManager implements Consumer<Integer> {
    private final Map<Integer, Long> clients;
    private final PoolDataSource pds;
    private final long timeoutMSec;

    public ActiveClientManager(PoolDataSource pds, long timeoutMSec) throws SQLException {
        clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        this.pds = pds;
        this.timeoutMSec = timeoutMSec;
    }

    private boolean isOffline(long currentTime, long limitTime) {
        return limitTime <= currentTime;
    }

    // Ищем, есть ли хоть один клиент с просроченным таймаутом
    private boolean searchTimeout(long currentTime) {
        for (Long val : clients.values()) {
            if (isOffline(currentTime, val))
                return true;
        };
        return false;
    }

    protected void updateState(Integer clientID, PreparedStatement stmt) throws SQLException {
        stmt.setInt(1, clientID);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }

    public void testTimeout() throws SQLException {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (!searchTimeout(currentTime))
            return;

        // Есть ли хоть один клиент с просроченным таймаутом. Создаем соединение
        List<Pair<Integer, SQLException>> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
                Connection con = pds.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clients SET state = NULL WHERE id = ?");
        ) {
            clients.entrySet().removeIf((entry) -> {
                // если время уже прошло
                if (isOffline(currentTime, entry.getValue())) {
                    // обновляем БД
                    try {
                        updateState(entry.getKey(), stmt);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        exceptions.add(new Pair<>(entry.getKey(), e));
                    }
                    // удаляем этот элемент
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
        // если в лямбде были исключения, обрабатываем
        if (exceptions.size() > 0)
          throw exceptions.get(0).getVal();
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Integer clientID) {
        long offlineTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeoutMSec;
        clients.compute(clientID, (key, oldval) -> {
            // Если запись новая - обновляем БД
            if (oldval == null) {
                try (
                        Connection con = pds.getConnection();
                        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE clients SET state = 1 WHERE id = ?");
                ) {
                    updateState(entry.getKey(), stmt);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            return offlineTime;
        });
    }
}
```